# first time on symfony framework and i had this problem syntax error, unexpected '{'

Tags: php

when i type this on cmd php bin/console make:migration
syntax error, unexpected '{'
i tried it all , i add ?> at the end for php balise nothing happen.
its my first time on symfony please be gentel and thanks

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProduitRepository")
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $libelle;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $prix;
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->;id;
    }
    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->;libelle;
    }
    public function setLibelle(string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->;libelle = $libelle;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPrix(): ?float
    {
        return $this->;prix;
    }
    public function setPrix(float $prix): self
    {
        $this->;prix = $prix;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have semicolons when you access the properties? Is this a symfony feature? Should it not be like: $this->id; etc.? The error lets you know that there is something wrong with the syntax. Does it not say on which line?

Also please add a tag for symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of the error you're seeing, but every line in that file containing `$this->` has a syntax error in it. You should not have a semicolon directly after the `->` in any of those lines - a semicolon only goes at the very end of a line. So `return $this->;id;` should be `return $this->id;`, `$this->;libelle = $libelle;` should be `$this->libelle = $libelle;`, etc. There are five of these errors in that class.

Try fixing these errors and running your migration command again. If you generate your entities with `bin/console make:entity` then Symfony should create these classes automatically for you without you needing to write your own getters and setters. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html